# Lua saving to file

Tags: file, lua

I'm working on a small project in Lua and having problem saving the score to disk.

My code is like this, and I do get the print message.

```
function saveHighScore(score)
    print("High score: "..tostring(score))
    local file = io.open("high_score.txt",'w')
    file:write(tostring(score))
    file:close()
end
```

Anyone out there that can help?

Comment: Literally not one single person in the world can help you. Principally because we have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Please add some error checks. Check if file is not nil, meaning it failed to open the file in the first place. Without errors or debug info we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. OK, so the score does not get written to the file. The file is there and I can read it. As stated, I get the print message, so the program is passing by the function. Any reason why it shouldn't work?

Comment: more info needed : what OS, where are you saving it

Comment: also did you add `require "io"` in your file?

Comment: @NekoNova, I do have require "io". I'm working in Lua Glider 2.0 on a Mac and just running in the simulator as an iPhone.

Comment: hmm, could be simulator issue, cause the code works fine on my console in mac.

Comment: @NekoNova. What a bummer. I get it to read in a score that I've manually put in the file, but it wont store a new one. Anyway I can check if it's going to work?

Comment: use homebrew and install lua, then run your code from command line. If it works there it's fine

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you would have solved it much faster if you followed first two comment's advices. Here is how it's done "in case someone else was stuck with the same problem and came across this":

```
function saveHighScore(score)
    print("High score: "..tostring(score))
    local file,err = io.open("high_score.txt",'w')
    if file then
        file:write(tostring(score))
        file:close()
    else
        print("error:", err) -- not so hard?
    end
end
```

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.open:

> io.open (filename [, mode])
>
> This function opens a file, in the mode specified in the string mode. It returns a new file handle, or, **in case of errors, nil plus an error message**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You can't save to the resource directory, only to the DocumentDirectory.

Here is the corrected code:

```
function saveHighScore(score)
    path = system.pathForFile("highScore.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    file = io.open(path,'w')
    file:write(tostring(score))
    io.close(file)
    print("High score: "..tostring(score))
    file = nil
end
```

Just wanted to post it in case someone else was stuck with the same problem and came across this.

Answer (score -1):

```
Number = math.random(1,100)
print("Try to guess a random number 1-100!")

while true do
local Guess = tonumber(io.read())
if Guess then

if Guess > Number then
print("Too high!")
end

if Guess < Number then
print("Too low!")
end

if Guess == Number then
print("Congratulations!")
return
end
else
print("Type a number >:(")
end
end
```